# Mysql SELECT name where all rows with the name have certain values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How would I write a query that would select the name of a person (a column in the row) given that they have enough rows to meet all conditions?

For example, I have a database set up like so:

```
name    permission_id
Bob     1
Bob     2
Jerry   3
Jerry   1
Jose    2
Billy   1
Billy   2
```

How would I only select the people that have permission id 1 and 2? In other words, I would like a query that checks every person by name to see if they have all the permissions requested.

In this example if I was to check for all users to who have permission 1 and 2 I should get Bob and Billy as a return value.

Here is my current query:

```
$this->db->select('center_user_permissions.id, center_users.first_name, center_users.last_name');
$this->db->from('center_user_permissions');
$this->db->where_in('permission_id', $permission_ids);
$this->db->join('center_users', 'center_users.center_id = center_user_permissions.center_id');
```

Currently this query returns anybody who has either permission id 1 or 2. I need it to be 1 AND 2. But I know I can't simply make two wheres because one particular row can't have both permission ids, but the query must check all rows for the specified ids.

I believe I would need a SELECT statement inside of my where? Can anybody tell me if I'm thinking correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to build this query in CodeIgniter, but you could `INNER JOIN` for each permission ID you want the user to have:

```
SELECT center_users.center_id, center_users.first_name, center_users.last_name
FROM center_users
INNER JOIN center_user_permissions AS p1 ON p1.center_id=center_users.center_id AND p1.permission_id=1
INNER JOIN center_user_permissions AS p2 ON p2.center_id=center_users.center_id AND p2.permission_id=2
```

You could check for more permissions by adding a `INNER JOIN` for each additional permission you wanted to require.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a in clause an an having for check that the user has both the permission

```
select  name 
from center_user_permissions 
where permissions_id in (1,2)
group by name
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Just make sure a name cant have twice the same permision. for example Jhon is a very common name. You should probably be using some ID.

Comment: Yep, I am using an id. I just chose a name for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select distinct(name),.. as name from 'center_user_permissions',center_users where 
center_users.center_id = center_user_permissions.center_id and permissions_id in (1,2)
```

substitute .. with your other fields and put in distinct the value that you want to be unique

Comment: The schema I provided is a very minimalistic example. In my actual schema there is a first name, last name, and id column.

Comment: please try this new solution @Nic

Answer (score 0):

## MySQL's [`GROUP BY` and `HAVING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Not user what kind of DB interface you're using in $this->db, but it may make things a little tricky. If I start with a raw SQL query:

```
SELECT
    center_user_permissions.id,
    center_users.first_name,
    center_users.last_name
FROM center_user_permissions
LEFT JOIN center_users
    ON center_users.center_id = center_user_permissions.center_id
WHERE center_user_permissions.permission_id in (1,2)
```

#### Group by `name`, where count of `permission_id` is > 1

This will group rows by `first_name` (so you'll only get one row for each unique name). Doing do allows you to run aggregate functions (`SUM()`, `MAX()`, `COUNT()`) against the rows that were "grouped" into a single row.

```
SELECT
    center_user_permissions.id,
    center_users.first_name,
    center_users.last_name
FROM center_user_permissions
LEFT JOIN center_users
    ON center_users.center_id = center_user_permissions.center_id
GROUP BY center_users.first_name
WHERE center_user_permissions.permission_id in (1,2)
HAVING COUNT(center_user_permissions.permission_id)>1
```